# Table listing of files with search

Tags: java

I have XML files stored in a folder. I would create a table with 5 columns:
Process No.: file name;
Name of patient: I will get the xml file there is information;
Date of creation: just see the file date;
Status: Full yes or no, this information is in the file;
Open: a button that opens the file of the line where is the button.

This part I managed more or less solved.

My main difficulty is that I want to appear only 10 files at a time. I need navigation button to go to the next and previous files.
And at the end of each column, I have a field that allows me to search for that column.

Here is a mockup that I created:

[image]

I work in Java with NetBeans.

Can anyone give me a tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination Concept is based on Total Results [ Count of Files,Records etc..] / Total Number of results per page.

For Example You have 87 Records and you want to display 6 pages per record

you will be having 15 pages with last page displaying 3 records only.

and you will be having three parameters monitoring index of page [ Previous, Current , Next]
First and Last pages are easy to display :)